# Create account with initial fund using web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts, ganache

Is it possible to create an account with initial fund using web3?

Every time  I create a new account I had to do fund transfer to add initial fund. If there is way to fund the account with minimum ETH while creating an account.